# Uninstall Tornado Web Server?

Tags: uninstall, tornado

I'm new to installing server frameworks but I don't see anywhere in the documentation of http://www.tornadoweb.org/ of how to uninstall this. Do I just remove the build folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just remove tornado's source code folder, which is probably located in ../python2.x/dist-packages. Keep in mind that Tornado is pure python.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling using python package manager pip.

First find the version of tornado installed

```
pip list | grep tornado
```

and then uninstall it,

```
pip uninstall tornado==<version-number>
```